# Login issues after relocating bin/bash

Tags: macos, bash, authentication, terminal

While trying to correct a terminal issue I moved the contents of 'bin/bash' to the desktop and deleted 'library>preferences>com.apple.terminal.plist' in hopes it will regenerate before I could place any contents in my 'bin/bash' my computer froze, now on reset I cannot login   (after bootup, selecting user and enter password it gets stuck on the loading spinner).

To correct this I reset and went into single-user mode ('command+s' on reset) checked the desktop and the contents of the bash were gone. Then checked the bash and I couldnt get into the dir so tried to reinstall Bash via brew 
But have a "connection failed" when signing into WiFi so my last attempt is to  '$resetpassword' and I reset to the same as my old hoping it would generate a file to allow me to login and again no luck.

Any suggestions. I'm still figuring out bash.
Im on osx Yosemite

Comment: This is why you made backups.

Comment: About to do that if I cannot figure it out can I don't want to lose a week and a half of my work

Comment: Deleting or moving /bin/bash might prevent access to the terminal, but I believe it will not prevent login. If you cannot login there may be other issues. Anyway, try to start in Safe Mode  (only essential OS X items are started; some features and apps might not work correctly) as explained [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18760?locale=en_US) and try to backup your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many other shells on the system:

```
/bin/sh
/bin/zsh
/bin/ksh
/bin/csh
```

Try going into single-user and copy sh to bash.

Also, don't mess with the system.

Comment: I like "copy `sh` to `bash`". On a Yosemite system, they differ in size by a few bytes, but `sh --version` produces the same output as `bash --version`.

Comment: Yup. Same on mine. It has a chance of working in this case.

Comment: I tried all of these suggestions and it didnt seem to fix it and I was getting weird key entries (incorrect key pressed outputs, before) so I messed up something before I even messed up this. I dont want the headache im just going to a backup. Thanks for the help. Hope this can help someone else though with a similair issue.